# How to send mail in Rails 3 from localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails. How does sending mail in Rails 3 work?

It tried the following, but it doesn't work:

Calling the mailer:

```
@invited_user = InviteUser.where(:email => @user.email)
```

Mailer:

```
class InviteUsersMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "qqqqqreply@qqqqqqqq.com"

    def invite_biller_email(inviter_details)
      @invitation_details = inviter_details
      @user = User.find(@invitation_details.request_sent_by)
      mail(:to => @invitation_details.email, :subject => "xxxxxxxxxxx")
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? If so, what did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way - use gmail to save having to set up your own mail server. In an initializer file (eg. inside `config/initializers/mailer.rb`), use the following code to adjust settings:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :domain => 'yourwebdomain.com',
  :user_name => 'username@gmail.com',
  :password => 'your password',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

After configuring, details on using the ActionMailer is found in the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

After you have checked that it works, you can try setting up your own mail server (alternatively, you might have a webhost that runs a mail server for you, in which case re-configure above settings to do that).

Comment: to add, if you want to limit this to an environment such as development-- you can drop this into a specific environment by using the above hash within `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {}`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the **[Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)** for sending mails.

In a nutshell there are two things you have to do:

1. Create a mailer
2. Configure a delivery method.

These steps and everything else is thoroughly covered in the Rails Guide.